# ¿Como se Google Cloud Messaging para enviar mensajes?

Tags: android, whatsapp, mensajes

Alguien sabe como usan GCM (Google Cloud Messaging), aplicaciones como WhatsAuto o similares, para enviar mensajes a mis contactos de Whatsapp, obtuve el manifest de WhatsAuto y vi que tiene estos permisos.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.future.whatslol.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.future.whatslol.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

Pero quisiera saber como los usa para enviar mensajes a mis contactos de WhatsApp

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud messaging ha sido sustituido por Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), si lo que ocupas es enviar una notificación push a ciertos dispositivos debes usar el servicio de FCM. En esencia, configuras una cuenta en Firebase, activas el servicio de Cloud Messaging, y lo configuras en tu app.

Ya que no existe un método del sdk-android-firebase que envié notificaciones, debes configurar un back-end personalizado, o bien, si solo ocupas enviar notificaciones como una especie de chat, puedes usar el API REST de FCM para enviar una notificación por método POST.

Te dejó un link a la documentación oficial de firebase, para que configures el servicio en tu app, y anexo un código de ejemplo de como usar Okhttp para enviar por POST una notificación "device to device".

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=es-419

También te comparto un tutorial de ALvarezTech, sin duda, explica muy simple como instalar el servicio. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTQ4d3ZUS8g

```
//First you need to add a OkhttpCliente dependency on your App Gradle File.
//You can find them in the next URL: https://github.com/square/okhttp


private void sendNotification(String regToken) {
        final String regToken2 = regToken;
        final String LEGACY_SERVER_KEY = "AIzaSyD6QliPCOBwISMu35_r_MzxSY6uc0gLd7s"; //Replace with your FCM Server Key
        final MediaType JSON
                = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

            new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
                        JSONObject dataJson=new JSONObject();
                        dataJson.put("body","Hi, this its a notification");
                        dataJson.put("title","hello world");
                        dataJson.put("sound", "/uri/audio/listen.mp3");
                        json.put("notification",dataJson);

                        json.put("to",regToken2);
                        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .header("Authorization","key="+ LEGACY_SERVER_KEY)
                                .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
                                .post(body)
                                .build();
                        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                        String finalResponse = response.body().string();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        //Log.d(TAG,e+"");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();

    }
```

Si te atoras en algo con gusto te puedo ayudar.